# Slack's notifications not working in full screen mode in Window 10

Tags: windows-10, slack

I am running Window 10 (1903) tried going to:

```
Notifications > Send notifications for: > All activity
```

And then:

- **Pressed**: <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
- **Typed**: `slack://notReallyWindows10`
- **Hit**: <kbd>Enter</kbd>

But when I run a game or play a video then the notifications don’t work. I think that when I in full screen mode Slack do not work.

How can I solve this?